# PHP foreach function doesnt work with my jquery code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, class

I have written this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var info = $('.info').detach();

$('.des').click(function(){
    score = score + 1;
    played = played + 1;
    $('.kreis').addClass("borderGreen");
    $('.foto').hide();
    $('.kreis').append(info);
});

$('.pro').click(function(){
    played = played + 1;
    $('.kreis').addClass("borderRed");
    $('.foto').hide();
    $('.kreis').append(info);

    console.log('score:' + score);
    console.log('played:' + played);
});

$('.frage').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(460, 0.7);
});

$('.frage').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(350, 0);
});
```

});

to achieve something like [this!](https://imgflip.com/gif/7tk98)

then I wrote the following php code to loop through that "function"

```
    <?php foreach ($objects as $object){ ?>

        <div class="kreis">
            <div class="info" >
                <div class="infobox">
                    <p style="padding-bottom:15px;border-bottom:1px solid #545454;"><?php echo $object["name"]; ?></p> <bl/>
                    <p style="font-weight:200;"><?php echo $object["position"]; ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="social">
                    <a href="<?php echo $object["twitter"]; ?>"><img src="img/twitter.png" style="width:45px;margin-left:35px;padding-right:12px;"></a>
                    <a><img src="img/dribbble.png" style="width:45px;"></a>
                </div>
            </div>  
                <div class="foto" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $object["img"]; ?>'); ">
                    <div class="frage">
                        <div class="des box"><p>AAAAA</p></div>
                        <div class="pro box" style="margin-top:6%;"><p>BBBBB</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div> <?php } ?>
```

Now the problem is, that if you click the .des or .pro object, jquery hides the layer of every object. Is there a way I can achieve what I want to do with jquery or do I have to use javascript or some other language? What is the most elegant way to solve this?

Comment: C is so so so far away from this ... c tag removed

Comment: You only have one variable holding the detached .info element, so this will never work with multiple instances of the above markup no matter how you twist and turn it.

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript

Comment: So you have a variable called $object that is an array?  WHAT function are you looping through?? You need to be way more specific.  JavaScript manipulates DOM.  PHP generates HTML markup the server serves up to the client which jquery can maniputlate.  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is perfect for this job. You can go with it.
But you have to change that only the current object in the click listener gets changed and not all of your objects. Try this:

```
$('.des').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    score = score + 1;
    played = played + 1;
    $this.closest('.kreis').addClass("borderGreen").append(info);
    $this.closest('.foto').hide();
});

$('.pro').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    played = played + 1;
    $this.closest('.kreis').addClass("borderRed").append(info);
    $this.closest('.foto').hide();

    console.log('score:' + score);
    console.log('played:' + played);
});
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but now the info class gets added to every object and not only to the closest one.

Comment: no, it will only be added to the closest element with the class `kreis`, because of function chaining. Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp. By the way a dom instance can only be the child of **one** parent dom object. So it is impossible, that there are multiple elements of the same instance in the dom tree.